# Why does a nested class with an implicitly-defined default constructor not satisfy std::default_initializable?

Tags: c++, static-assert, implicit-constructor

In the following code, only Bar3 fails.  What is the reason behind this static assertion failure?

```
#include <concepts>
struct Bar1 { Bar1() = default; bool val = false; };
static_assert(std::default_initializable<Bar1>);
struct Bar2 { Bar2() {} bool val = false; };
static_assert(std::default_initializable<Bar2>);
class Foo {
public:
    struct Bar3 { Bar3() = default; bool val = false; };
    static_assert(std::default_initializable<Bar3>);        // <-- only this one fails
    struct Bar4 { Bar4() {} bool val = false; };
    static_assert(std::default_initializable<Bar4>);
};
```

Comment: Seems to be something to do with the class being incomplete, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/4Tc1qALg5eXPrbA8

Comment: @MarkB There is a typo Bar4() {} bool val = false;

Comment: No @vlad, that bit's ok

Comment: @PaulSanders And what does this construction mean?

Comment: @user17732522 I am sorry. I was not attentive.

Comment: @vlad It's just a bunch of stuff all crammed into one line that would normally be on separate lines.